# Unable to execute Suite in Parallel Mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng-eclipse

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
  <parameter name="browser" value="firefox">
    <classes>
      <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1"/>
    </classes>
     </parameter>

     <test thread-count="5" name="chromeTest">
     <parameter name="browser" value="chrome">
     <classes>
      <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1"/>
     </classes>
     </parameter>

</test> <!-- Test -->     
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Java code:

```
package Crossbrowser;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1 {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void setup(String browser) throws Exception{
        //Check if parameter passed from TestNG is 'firefox'
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
        //create firefox instance
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        //Check if parameter passed as 'chrome'
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            //set path to chromedriver.exe
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
            //create chrome instance
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        //Check if parameter passed as 'Edge'
                else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Edge")){
                    //set path to Edge.exe
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","‪F:\\New folder (2)\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
                    //create Edge instance
                    driver = new EdgeDriver();
                }
        else{
            //If no browser passed throw exception
            throw new Exception("Browser is not correct");
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testParameterWithXML() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/header[1]/ss-header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/a[1]")).click();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        //Find user name
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ss-auth-form[1]/md-card[1]/ss-login-form[1]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]"));
        //Fill user name
        userName.sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        //Find password
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ss-auth-form[1]/md-card[1]/ss-login-form[1]/div[1]/form[1]/input[2]"));
        //Fill password
        password.sendKeys("1234567890");

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@name='myForm']//ss-submit-button[@label='Log In']//input[@class='submit']")).click();
    }
}
```

While executing as Single Suite the code below is working fine, but when doing the same in parallel mode, I am getting the error:

> The content of element type "test" must match
>   "(method-selectors?,parameter*,groups?,packages?,classes?)".

Why am I getting this error?

**PS:** When executed in separate web browsers I am not getting this error. I only get it when started running in parallel mode.

Comment: You are almost correct, You just need to close </Test> after completing <parameter> of Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the thread count in suite level and change your testng xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
     <test name="chromeTest">
     <parameter name="browser" value="chrome">
     <classes>
      <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1"/>
     </classes>
     </parameter>

</test> <!-- Test -->     
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following XML. This worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5" >
    <test name="FirefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
        <classes>
            <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="chromeTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <class name="Crossbrowser.Test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```